# I am trying to implement CORS to my JavaScript code correctly, and it worked for a while, I believe I am missing some file from the project?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, cross-domain

I get a CORS error from my browser.
I am trying to implement CORS to my JavaScript code correctly, and I had it 
successfully for a while. This is my code, which should work because it worked before. I might have accidentally removed some line which included the file that I need. I am including JQuery, and Cross Origin and I have Cross Origin in my query in the way that is described in documentation. I'm not sure what may be missing. Something is missing probably. Am I including everything?

(From what I remember I may have had another min.js file)

This is my code which is pretty clean I think... :

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.ajax-cross-origin.min.js"></script>




<script>


var theText;

          $(function() {
                  $('#b1').click(
                    function() {


                      $.ajax({
                            crossOrigin: true,

                            url: "https://uselessfacts.jsph.pl/random.json?language=en",
                            success: function(data) {


                            }
                          });
                          $.ajaxSetup({
                            crossOrigin: true
                          });
                          $.getJSON("https://uselessfacts.jsph.pl/random.json?language=en",
                          null, 
                          function(data) {

                                    var text = JSON.parse((data))
                                    theText = text["text"];
                                  //  console.log(theText)

                          });

                            $('#input').val(theText);





                    }

  );
});
</script>
```

Other than that; could it be that I didn't set everything up the right way?

Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this happens on your development server, and you are using chrome, there is extension for chrome that allow cors ([check it out](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?hl=en)). So you may try that. Other than that, i do not know what might be an issue, since the code is working for me just fine.

Comment: I did system restore to one day ago and it fixed it. Something was off for sure maybe one of the variables.